# How to avoid TagManager.initialize() running many times?

Tags: reactjs, react-gtm-module

I use react-gtm-module (version 2.0.11) to create Google Tag Manager for my ReactJs app.

My problem is that each time a component renders, the function TagManager.initialize runs again. This creates duplicate GTM scripts (as attached).

I have to get gtm-ID from other data which changes many times. Each time this data changes, my component renders.

Is there a way to avoid the function TagManager.initialize run again if my GTM is already initialized?

My code:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (data.gtm_id){
     TagManager.initialize({
      gtmId: data.gtm_id,
     });
   }
}, [data.gtm_id])
```

Thank you so much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you add a check for any object added by TagManager, like `dataLayer` or `google_tag_data` in `window`, you can prevent unnecessary reinitializations.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (data.gtm_id && !window.dataLayer){
     TagManager.initialize({
      gtmId: data.gtm_id,
     });
   }
}, [data.gtm_id])
```